# Javascript: Remove top X items from an array where property matches without forEach?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a javascript array of objects that has something like this in it:

```
[{
  orderId: 1,
  orderLine: 1,
  itemId: 123,
  qty: 1
 },
 {
  orderId: 2,
  orderLine: 4,
  itemId: 123,
  qty: 2
 },
 {
  orderId: 3,
  orderLine: 7,
  itemId: 234,
  qty: 1
 },
 {
  orderId: 4,
  orderLine: 8,
  itemId: 123,
  qty: 1
 }
]
```

I also have a second array that has the number of items matching the itemId on hand.

```
[{
   itemId: 123,
   qty: 3
 },
 {
   itemId: 234,
   qty: 4
 }
]
```

I want to get a list of the orders that cannot be fulfilled by the quantity of the items.

Currently, I am thinking a forEach loop on the order array, filter the item array to match itemId and then reduce the item array quantity of the matched item by the quantity ordered.  If the quantity in the filtered item is 0, then that order cannot be fulfilled.

Problem is that we know forEach loops are going to be inefficient.  Is there some other way I can remove the items that match the property of the itemId by the quantity available? Essentially skim the top X orders off the order array in one pass?

Now that I think about it, it would also have to take in some logic such as, if the quantity ordered is greater than the quantity available while the quantity available is greater than zero, skip that order and go to the next one.

So, using the data above, currently the only order that would be returned would be orderId 4, since I have 3 of item 123 and orders 1 and 2 would be fulfilled.  I also have 4 of item 234 and only 1 ordered so it would be fulfilled.  However, if i only had 2 of item 123, then orders 1 and 4 would be fulfilled since 1 went to order 1 (processing top down) and 2 were ordered for 2, but having only 1 left I skipped this and order 4, ordering 1 was also fulfilled.

Any suggestions on a better way to do this skimming than a forEach?

Comment: I'd strongly suggest turning that inventory array into an object that's keyed on product id. Then you can use a single `reduce` pass on your order array to determine all the orders that you won't be able to fulfill.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans My thoughts, exactly.

Comment: `forEach` is inefficient? You are bound to go over all items, whether the function is called `map`, `reduce` or `forEach`. Premature Optimization Is the Root of All Evil.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`map` the orders array and substract the quantity from the available items array and whenever the avaialble `qty` is below `0` return the `orderId`, keep in mind that the `available` array will be mutated, if you want to preserve it , make a copy, the result will be an array of order Ids that can not be fulfilled :

```js
const orders = [
  {
    orderId: 1,
    orderLine: 1,
    itemId: 123,
    qty: 1
  },
  {
    orderId: 2,
    orderLine: 4,
    itemId: 123,
    qty: 2
  },
  {
    orderId: 3,
    orderLine: 7,
    itemId: 234,
    qty: 1
  },
  {
    orderId: 4,
    orderLine: 8,
    itemId: 123,
    qty: 1
  }
];

const available = [
  {
    itemId: 123,
    qty: 3
  },
  {
    itemId: 234,
    qty: 4
  }
];

// make a copy if you want to preserve the available object
// const availableCopy = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(available));

const result = orders
  .map(({ orderId, qty, itemId }) => {
    const itm = available.find(e => e.itemId === itemId);
    itm.qty = itm.qty - qty;

    return itm.qty < 0 ? orderId : null;
  })
  .filter(e => e);

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Thanks!  I should have thought of that.  I modified it a little using reduce instead to return the entire object and not just the orderId itself.